# Wrong output with map C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote the following code for constructing std::pair as key to unordered_map. However, I dont know why I am getting all 0's as output of vector. Can someone please suggest as to where am I going wrong?

```
struct key_hash
{
    size_t operator()(const std::pair<unsigned,unsigned>& key) const
    {
        return uint64_t((key.first << 32) | key.second);
    }
};

typedef std::unordered_map<std::pair<unsigned,unsigned>, std::vector<unsigned>, key_hash> MyMap;


int main()
{    
    MyMap m;
    vector<unsigned> t;
    t.push_back(4);
    t.push_back(5);
    m[make_pair(4294967292,4294967291)]=t;

    for(vector<unsigned>::iterator i=m[make_pair(4294967292,4294967291)].begin(),j=m[make_pair(2147483645,2147483643)].end();i!=j;++i)
        cout<<"vec="<<(*i)<<"\n";

    cout<<"vector empty. \n";
}
```

Comment: Could it be something with the literals? Make them unsigned maybe? Just a thought.

Comment: To debug, please try to reduce the possible problem space. Can you reproduce the problem if you make the value type a simple data type, such as `int`? Can you test the hash function directly? Does it produce the expected output? Does the `unordered_map` work when the values in the pair are really small (`make_pair(1, 1)`)?

Comment: @MagnusHoff Yes it works when the values are really small...

Comment: `(key.first << 32)` has undefined behavior if `key.first` does not have *more* than 32 bits (which it most likely has not). You need to cast to a bigger type *before* shifting.

Comment: exactly my observation, first copy it to 64 register, then shift it, else it will be bad hashing function

Comment: Try providing a sample of actual code that exhibits your problem.  You've left out things like header files.   Also specify your compiler.   The expression `key.first << 32` causes undefined behaviour unless an `unsigned` is 33 (yes 33) bits or more.

Comment: what does this mean? `for(vector<unsigned>::iterator i=m[make_pair(4294967292,4294967291)].begin(),j=m[make_pair(2147483645,2147483643)].end();i!=j;++i)` maybe you want `m[make_pair(4294967292,4294967291)].end()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**i** and **j** are iterators to 2 different vector's and they cannot be compared. Using debug iterators might catch this under visual studio.

This code: `j=m[make_pair(2147483645,2147483643)].end();` will create a new empty vector since the key is different from the previously used one.

Whem initializing **j** like this: `j=m[make_pair(4294967292,4294967291)].end();` the results are fine:

`vec=4
vec=5
vector empty.`

Comment: Actually that's not true... if OP fixes the other bugs, i and j refer to the same vector and can be compared.

Comment: I think he's saying the key _isn't_ different and that that is the problem.

Comment: @onqtan: But that was just a typo! :-(

Comment: @einpoklum isn't that "typo" the root of the problem?

Comment: @onqtam: It's indistinguishable from a typo in copying the code to SO, so I kind of tend to ignore/not notice these things... but OP did accept your answer, so I guess you're right.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting undefined behaviour, since `m[make_pair(4294967292,4294967291)]` and `m[make_pair(2147483645,2147483643)]` are probably different objects (unless something very strange with overflow wrapping is happening).

Comment: I think actually that's just a typo and not what OP meant... :-)

Comment: this is absolutely the problem. He's iterating from the begin() of one vector to the end() of another. Disaster is inevitable.

Comment: Plus there is the problem of shifting 32-bit, and the incomplete example (missing headers etc.)...

Answer (score 3):

1. You may have a typo with the literals - just do `key = make_pair(...u,...u)`.
2. Your hash functor probably has an overflow - `unsigned int` is probably 32-bit on your system).
3. Your literals probably exceed the maximum value of signed integers, and are not specified to be unsigned.

Answer (score 2):

try changing your hash function to something along those lines:

```
struct key_hash
 {
     size_t operator()(const std::pair<unsigned,unsigned>& key) const
     {
         uint64_t tmp = key.first;
         tmp = tmp << 32;
         return uint64_t(tmp | key.second);                                                                                                                                                              
      }
 };
```

I have also added the one instance of the pair so changed the main to :

```
MyMap m;
vector<unsigned> t;
t.push_back(4);
t.push_back(5);
auto a =  make_pair(4294967292,4294967291);
m[a]=t;

for(vector<unsigned>::iterator i=m[a].begin(),j=m[a].end();i!=j;++i)
    cout<<"vec="<<(*i)<<"\n";

cout<<"vector empty. \n";
```

This gave me the correct output:

```
vec=4
vec=5
vector empty.
```

Answer (score 2):

Tidying up the loop to make it clear (and ignoring the warning about a 32-bit left-shift on a 32-bit value...)

What you are doing is this:

```
const auto& first_vector = m[make_pair(4294967292,4294967291)];
const auto& second_vector = m[make_pair(2147483645,2147483643)];

for(auto iter = begin(first_vector) ; 
    iter != end(second_vector) ; // <<=== SEE THE PROBLEM?
    ++iter)
{
  // ...
}
```

Incrementing the iterator of one vector will never yield the end() of a different one so your loop is infinite, until you get a segfault because you've accessed memory that does not belong to you.